# javafx in swing exception "Toolkit not initialized"

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I've read the post:
[JavaFx 2.x - Swing : Not on FX application thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182592/javafx-2-x-swing-not-on-fx-application-thread/12202749#12202749)

with reference to "
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized "

I have found a discussion here [JavaFX 2.1: Toolkit not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273773/javafx-2-1-toolkit-not-initialized)

but I am not able to use the solution

"Istantiate JFXPanel in Swing Event Dispatcher Thread:"

because it stay undefined time waiting.

I have your same problem using a JInternalFrame inside a JDesktopPane.

I've tried:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    final JFXPanel javafxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    latch.countDown();       
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    javafxPanel.setScene( new Scene(pane) {
      Text text = new Text("Hello World");            
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(javafxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
});        
this.add(frame);
try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.println("err");
    Logger.getLogger(WorkspacePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,     ex);
}
```

Where frame is a JInternalFrame and this is a JDesktopPane.

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because it stay undefined time waiting.

This waiting can be caused by the `latch`. If the code you posted is triggered on the Event Dispatch Thread, the `latch.await()` call will block the EDT and making sure the `Runnable` which you posted on the EDT will never executed, hence the `latch.countDown()` statement is never reached. You can quickly check this with the method `EventQueue.isDispatchThread`.

I would strongly suggest to simply remove the `CountDownLatch`, as running that code on another `Thread` is not an option since you are working with Swing components, which should be accessed/modified/created/... on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Further, once you have removed the latch you will encounter the same exception as in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12182592/1076463). The

```
javafxPanel.setScene( new Scene(pane) {
  Text text = new Text("Hello World");            
});
```

must be executed on the JavaFX thread and not on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184250/1076463) on that question on how to solve that.